# I want a JavaScript process to have different permissions than the user that executes it

Tags: 2013, list, javascript, permissions

I want to have a page where the user can click a button executing a javascript process that can read and modify list records for a list that the user has no access to.  Can a user execute a process that has different permissions than him?  Or is the process ALWAYS inheriting the permissions of the user executing it?

I'm trying to have JavaScript read a record from a list and delete that record so that no one else can use it and not give direct access rights to that list so that I can prevent them from tampering with the values in that list. I want to keep them from adding back used numbers, or deleting proper numbers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible with JavaScript, that is a huge security problem.

Comment: The old guideline that I have used is that Javascript automates end users actions, (if the end user knew what to do). If you build a security model into it, then the end user may choose not to use the script. Many sites have given themselves away to this model.

Answer (score 0):

Create Application Page and do jquery ajax call to that page. Inside that page, in page load method get query string parameters and do whatever you want.

Comment: Along the same lines: Consider using a workflow to make updates. Submit a request to update the master list to the request queue list and allow the workflow to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, JavaScript code runs in the context of the browser AND the user who browses the page. If you could "elevate" permissions or "impersonate" another user, as the code is client-side (meaning any user could inject such a script) that would be a huge security breach!
So, any action made by the user is made on behalf of the user, there's no way around that.

[note: that's why apps for SharePoint Online are so a pain in the a**!]

In your case, you'd need to develop/deploy server-side code, including your business logic and elevation/impersonation/whatever. Then, open an access to that code through a Web service (or anything else) and call it from JavaScript (or from any client-side action)... but it will be your responsability to check whether the action from the user is allowed as per your requirements.